# Use GOOGLE maps in iOS supporting iOS 6 and also iOS 5

Tags: ios5, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am in a need of having maps support for an app, but the concern is prior to ios 6 the iOS mapKit uses the google maps which is rich in content, but in iOS 6 its using its own maps which is not that rich in content.

I have search for the Google API for ios 6, which is great but I need to support prior to ios 6 also.

Please help.

Comment: Please help with what?

Answer (score 2):

The new Google Maps SDK for iOS supports back to iOS 5.1, see here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro#supported_platforms

Comment: Not any more! iOS6 and up. The adoption of iOS6 is so high I'd recommend dropping iOS5 support anyway, unless you have an annoying client like I do.